# Is the line graph of a Hamilton-connected graph is also Hamilton-connected?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

If a graph G is Hamilton-connected, is it true that its line graph must also be Hamilton-connected? If yes, how to show it, and if no, what would be the counter example?

We know that converse of this statement is not true. I mean the line graph of the Petersen graph is Hamilton-connected, but Petersen graph itself is not Hamilton-connected.

Answer (score 0):

If the line graph is Hamilton-connected, then it is also Hamiltonian. This means that the original graph is Eulerian. The complete graph $K_4$ is Hamilton-connected, but not Eulerian (too many vertices of odd degree).

Comment: Would you be a little more specific? Are you suggesting that the statement is obviously true? Certainly, both K4 and its line graph are Hamilton-connected.